# Issue in setting up inbound calling with FreePBX in docker with a DID number?

Tags: mobile, asterisk, voip, freepbx

I have a **DDI number** +8XXXXXXXXXXXXXX from sip.ippi.fr and I tried setting it directly on zoiper phone and when I made a call from my mobile number it worked. I want to set this inside freePBX.
So, I set up **a trunk with all the sip.ippi.fr details** and I created a **inbound route with "+8XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"** (and once with the +) "8XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" as my DID number and set the destination as an extension. I have given the **context as "from-trunk"** in the trunk. 
Now, when I try to call this DID number over the phone, I just get an reply that the number is not available. I checked the CDR reports, there is nothing updated there. So the call does not reach the server at all.

I am using asterisk 13 with freepbx setup on docker. Is there any configuration that I am missing ?

Comment: **The call does reach the server, and I get these logs** : 
`[2015-11-26 16:51:54] WARNING[23615][C-00000016]:     chan_sip.c:22232 func_header_read: This function can only be used on SIP channels.


                                                                                                                  
[2015-11-26 16:51:54] WARNING[23615][C-00000016]: Ext. s:3 @ from-trunk: Friendly Scanner from`

Comment: Docker can do nat or firewall needed ports. Please consult your setup files.

Comment: As call is not even reaching to your server, none of your Freepbx configuration will come in effect. To handle call on your pbx it should at least reach to your server. Are you sure your DID provider routing call to your server ? Also enable sip debug and see if any single sip request comes to your server for that call

Answer (score 0):

You need to register to your provider directly as you did with zoiper. Try to register your asterisk to the sip.ippi.fr so that provider can route the calls to your freepbx, then you can distribute the call whatever you like.